# Bicep pass storage account connection string to key vault secret

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-storage-account, azure-bicep

I have been browsing about this but I couldn't find any practical or useful solution.

I am deploying a storage account using bicep. This works just fine, but I am trying to get the storage account connection string and store as a secret into a azure key vault.

So far I have the following code

```
param tenantCode array = [
  'dsec'
]

param storageAccounts string = 'sthrideveur'

resource storage_Accounts 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2021-06-01' = [ for tenantcode in tenantCode :{
  name: 'stnmeur${tenantcode}'
  location: 'westeurope'
  sku: {
    name: 'Standard_RAGRS'
  }
  kind: 'StorageV2'
  properties: {
    allowCrossTenantReplication: true
    minimumTlsVersion: 'TLS1_2'
    allowBlobPublicAccess: false
    allowSharedKeyAccess: true
    networkAcls: {
      bypass: 'AzureServices'
      virtualNetworkRules: []
      ipRules: []
      defaultAction: 'Allow'
    }
    supportsHttpsTrafficOnly: true
    encryption: {
      services: {
        file: {
          keyType: 'Account'
          enabled: true
        }
        blob: {
          keyType: 'Account'
          enabled: true
        }
      }
      keySource: 'Microsoft.Storage'
    }
    accessTier: 'Cool'
  }
}]

resource devkeyvault 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2021-06-01-preview' existing = {
  name : 'keyvayltname'
}
```

I found this code but unfortunately it comes with no explanation and is not working for me

```
resource keyVault 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2019-09-01' existing = {
  name: last(split(keyVaultId, '/'))
  resource storageSecret 'secrets' = {
    name: 'StorageAccount-ConnectionString'
    properties: {
    value: 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=${storageAccountName};AccountKey=${listKeys(storageAccount.id, storageAccount.apiVersion).keys[1].value}'
   }
  }
}
```

Can any one please explain me how to achieve this if its possible. thank you so much for any help

UPDATE:

So I did some update to my code:

```
param tenantCode array = [
  'dsec'
]

var storageName = [for item in tenantCode :{
  name: string('sthrideveur${item}')
}]


var connectionStringSecretName = [for n in storageName :{
  name: '${n.name}'
}]





resource storage_Accounts 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2021-06-01' = [ for name in storageName :{
  name: '${name.name}'
  location: 'westeurope'
  sku: {
    name: 'Standard_RAGRS'
  }
  kind: 'StorageV2'
  properties: {
    allowCrossTenantReplication: true
    minimumTlsVersion: 'TLS1_2'
    allowBlobPublicAccess: false
    allowSharedKeyAccess: true
    networkAcls: {
      bypass: 'AzureServices'
      virtualNetworkRules: []
      ipRules: []
      defaultAction: 'Allow'
    }
    supportsHttpsTrafficOnly: true
    encryption: {
      services: {
        file: {
          keyType: 'Account'
          enabled: true
        }
        blob: {
          keyType: 'Account'
          enabled: true
        }
      }
      keySource: 'Microsoft.Storage'
    }
    accessTier: 'Cool'
  }
}]


resource keyVault 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2019-09-01' existing = {
  name : 'XXXX'
}

// Store the connection string in KV if specified
resource storageAccountConnectionString 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets@2019-09-01' = {
  name: '${connectionStringSecretName[0].name}'
  properties: {
    value: 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=${storage_Accounts[0]};AccountKey=${listKeys('${storage_Accounts[0].id}', '${storage_Accounts[0].apiVersion}').keys[0].value};EndpointSuffix=${environment().suffixes.storage}'
  }
}
```

But when I run the template I get this error

```
InvalidTemplate - Deployment template validation failed: 'The template resource 'sthrideveurdsec' for type 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets' at line '1' and column '1378' has incorrect segment lengths. A nested resource type must have identical number of segments as its resource name. A root resource type must have segment length one greater than its resource name. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template/#resources for usage details.'.
```

I see in the error that the name is correct but I don't fully understand what I am doing wrong with the segment length

Comment: Do you have any error while deploying the bicep file ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make sure that the key vault has the `Azure Resource Manager for template deployment` option enable:

[image]

If you have networking enable on key vault, make sure the `Allow trusted Microsoft services to bypass this firewall` is enabe:

[image]

The user or service principal deploying the bicep file also need permission to create secrets in key vault.

You can then add the storage connectionstring like this:

```bicep
param storageAccountName string
...
param keyVaultName string
param connectionStringSecretName string = '${storageAccountName}-connectionstring'

// Create storage account
resource storageAccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2019-06-01' = {
  name: storageAccountName
  ...
}

// Get reference to KV
resource keyVault 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2019-09-01' existing = {
  name: keyVaultName
}

// Store the connection string in KV if specified
resource storageAccountConnectionString 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets@2019-09-01' = {
  name: connectionStringSecretName
  parent: keyVault
  properties: {
    value: 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=${storageAccount.name};AccountKey=${storageAccount.listKeys().keys[0].value};EndpointSuffix=${environment().suffixes.storage}'
  }
}
```

if you're using an array, you could do something like that:

```bicep
param storageAccountNames array
...
param keyVaultName string

// Create storage accounts
resource storageAccounts 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2019-06-01' = [ for name in storageAccountNames :{
  name: name
  ...
}]

// Get reference to KV
resource keyVault 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2019-09-01' existing = {
  name: keyVaultName
}

// Store the connectionstrings in KV if specified
resource storageAccountConnectionStrings 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets@2019-09-01' = [ for (name, i) in storageAccountNames :{
  name: '${name}-connectionstring'
  parent: keyVault
  properties: {
    value: 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=${storageAccounts[i].name};AccountKey=${listKeys(storageAccounts[i].listKeys().keys[0].value};EndpointSuffix=${environment().suffixes.storage}'
  }
}]
```

Comment: Dear Thomas, thank you so much for your reply. I have a question. As you can see in my code. The storage Account name is part of a for loop on which I concat a fixed string to the `tenant code` to generate always a different storage account. While in the `connectionStringSecretName` is a string value. To achieve this, do I need to create a separate for loop? and how can I make sure that the connection string name matches the for loop output?

Comment: I've added a sample for array